How to get a background color to fill the entire page
I'm trying to practice building a website using Angular and I'm trying to fill the background with a color gradient. However, when I set the css to fill the background it only goes up till the div container. How do I get the entire page to fill with the gradient in under the html style tag.
index.html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tutorial3</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>

app.component.html:

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card bg-custom-1">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h2 class="card-title text-left text-white py-3">Tutorial3</h2>
          <ul class="text-left list-inline py-3">
            <li class="list-inline-item">
              <a routerLink="/games" class="btn btn-info">List</a>
                </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

styles.css:

html{
    height:100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(60,43,91), rgb(153,39,77));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
}

app.component.css:
.bg-custom-1{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(46,37,56,1),rgba(46,37,56,0.75))
}

website:
enter image description here
I tried placing the gradient on the html and a separate gradient on the div so that it would blend in, but the space around the header is just white.

Try applying the gradient to the body element and add "height: 100%" to the body element. You could also try the same approach to the div in  AppComponent

You could just set the background color on the body { }

So I fiddled with changing the styles.css by changing the gradient from html to body and it turns out I have to put the same settings to both body and html.
html{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(60,43,91), rgb(153,39,77));
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;  
}
body{
    height:100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(60,43,91), rgb(153,39,77));
}


Yes! The height is here the key. You can do this:
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
For body you can define your background...

in styles.css, try replacing height:100vh with height:100% and also add width:100% to it.
